# Update response doesn't fetch the updated eves object in Rem entity

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to update eves object in Rem Model entity. Refer the below request and response body. The request body Which I tried to update contains 2 eves object, but the response shows only one eves object. It updates the eves object correctly, but it's not fetching the 2 eves object in the put response. I tried fetching the result in Get call and it fetches the 2 eves response correctly, I am not sure why it's not showing newly created eves when I try to create the eves via update call.

**Code:**

```
if (remInput.getEves() != null) {
            updateEves(id, remInput.getEves());
        }
    
        remRepository.save(rem);

        return findById(id);
}
```

**Update Request:**

```
{
  "eves": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "eves_type": "Mems",
      "from_date": "2024-03-10T10:45:30",
      "to_date": "2024-03-11T10:45:30",
      "address": {
        "address1": "Main street",
        "address2": "Kc kuppam",
        "landmark": "Near statue",
        "country": "India",
        "state": "TN",
        "district": "Chennai",
        "city": "Chennai",
        "pincode": "602201"
      }
    },
    {
      "from_date": "2023-12-04T12:45:29.294+00:00",
      "to_date": "2023-12-05T12:45:29.294+00:00",
      "eves_type": "Subbha"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "message": "Rem 1 updated",
    "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "deceased": {
            "id": 1,
            "password": null,
            "home": null,
            "created_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:08.195+00:00",
            "modified_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:08.195+00:00",
            "status": "Active",
            "initial": "Mr.",
            "name": "Suresh1",
            "last_name": "Babu",
            "email": "suresh1@gmail.com",
            "nick_name": "Suresh1",
            "gender": "m",
            "birth_date": "1960-11-30T12:45:00.000+00:00",
            "death_date": "2024-12-28T10:45:00.000+00:00",
            "home_address": {
                "city": "Chennai",
                "state": "TN",
                "country": "India",
                "pincode": "602201",
                "address1": "Main street",
                "address2": "Kc kuppam",
                "district": "Chennai",
                "landmark": "Near statue"
            },
            "age_in_years": 64,
            "age_in_months": 0,
            "age_in_days": 28
        },
        "death": null,
        "created_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:28.847+00:00",
        "modified_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:48.819+00:00",
        "created_by": null,
        "modified_by": null,
        "email": null,
        "deceased_id": null,
        "death_address": {
            "city": "Chennai",
            "state": "TN",
            "country": "India",
            "pincode": "602201",
            "address1": "Main street",
            "address2": "Kc kuppam",
            "district": "Chennai",
            "landmark": "Near statue"
        },
        "eves": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "modified_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:48.815+00:00",
                "eves_type": "Memorial Service",
                "address": {
                    "address1": "Main street",
                    "address2": "Kc kuppam",
                    "landmark": "Near statue",
                    "country": "India",
                    "state": "TN",
                    "district": "Chennai",
                    "city": "Chennai",
                    "pincode": "602201"
                },
                "from_date": "2024-03-10T10:45:00.000+00:00",
                "to_date": "2024-03-10T10:45:00.000+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Sample Response from fetch call:**

```
 "eves": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "location": null,
                    "created_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:48.808+00:00",
                    "modified_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:48.808+00:00",
                    "eves_type": "Subha",
                    "address": null,
                    "from_date": "2023-12-04T12:45:00.000+00:00",
                    "to_date": "2023-12-04T12:45:00.000+00:00"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "created_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:29.561+00:00",
                    "modified_date": "2024-03-14T05:02:48.815+00:00",
                    "eves_type": "Mems",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "Chennai",
                        "state": "TN",
                        "country": "India",
                        "pincode": "602201",
                        "address1": "Main street",
                        "address2": "Kc kuppam",
                        "district": "Chennai",
                        "landmark": "Near statue"
                    },
                    "from_date": "2024-03-10T10:45:00.000+00:00",
                    "to_date": "2024-03-10T10:45:00.000+00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: How do you know which entity to update for the second update request, when you don't provide an id? And why aren't you providing the responsible code for the response itself, eg controller method, entity fetch, ...

Comment: @Slevin It's updating correctly I have mentioned my response doesn't shows newly created obj response in PUT call response, When I fetch the same in fetch call its showing correct response. My question is why it's not showing in newly created eves object in put call response. See above i have added service code

Comment: `return findById(id);` will fetch the entity for this specific id. You're not fetching anymore, and your code doesn't reflect what you are saying. It's just a very small excerpt, and nobody can tell anything what's going on as long as you're not providing more code. I don't know your controller method, I don't know your service/repository code, I don't know anything.